# WordPress + Gulp - browserSync won't update my .php files

Tags: php, html, wordpress, gulp

SCSS and JS files work as used to but when I save .php files it reloads browser but it not update html..

here is my gulpfile.js

I'v tried to separate watch functions and tried to add some delay but with no sucess

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const { src, dest, watch, series } = require('gulp');

 // styles
      const scss = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
      const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
      const cssMinify = require('gulp-clean-css');
      const concat = require('gulp-concat');
      const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

      function styles(){
            return src([
                  './wp-content/themes/savez-tema/src/scss/vendor/_bootstrap.min.scss',
                  './wp-content/themes/savez-tema/src/scss/**/*.scss'
            ])
                  .pipe( scss() )
                  .pipe( autoprefixer('last 2 versions') )
                  .pipe( cssMinify() )
                  .pipe( dest('./wp-content/themes/savez-tema/dist/css'))
                  .pipe(browserSync.stream()); 
      }
 // scripts
 const jsMinify = require('gulp-terser');

 function scripts(){
      return src ([
            './wp-content/themes/savez-tema/src/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js',
            './wp-content/themes/savez-tema/src/js/**/*.js'
      ])
            .pipe(concat('main.js'))
            .pipe( jsMinify() )
            .pipe( dest('./wp-content/themes/savez-tema/dist/js'))
            .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})); // proveri
 }

 // watch
function watchTask(){
      browserSync.init({
            proxy: 'http://localhost:8888/savez', 
      });
      
      watch(['./wp-content/themes/savez-tema/**/*.php', './wp-content/themes/savez-tema/src/scss/**/*.scss', './wp-content/themes/savez-tema/src/js/**/*.js'],

      series(styles, scripts))
}

exports.default = series(styles, scripts, watchTask)
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time trying different aproaches here is working solution:

P.S - if using MAMP disable PHP-Cache This is MUST!

```
// REQUIREMENTS
const { src, dest, watch, series, parallel } = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const php = require('gulp-connect-php');

// PATHS
const paths = {
  scss: {
    src: './wp-content/themes/savez-tema/src/scss/**/*.scss',
    dest: './wp-content/themes/savez-tema/dist/css'
  },
  js: {
    src: './wp-content/themes/savez-tema/src/js/**/*.js',
    dest: './wp-content/themes/savez-tema/dist/js/'
  }
};

// BROWSER SYNC WITH PHP INSIDE SERVER
function sync() {
  php.server({
    base: './savez/',
    port: 3000,
    keepalive: true,
    // custom PHP locations
    bin: '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.33/bin/php',
    ini: '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.33/conf/php.ini',
    reloadOnRestart: true,
  });
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: "http://localhost:8888/savez/",
    baseDir: "./savez",
    notify: false,
    reloadOnRestart: true,
  });
}

// TASKS
function compileSass() {
  return src(paths.scss.src)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: ".min.css" }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(dest(paths.scss.dest))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function compileJs() {
  return src(paths.js.src)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(dest(paths.js.dest))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

// WATCH
function watchSass() {
  watch(paths.scss.src, compileSass)
}

function watchJs() {
  watch(paths.js.src, compileJs)
  console.log(paths.js.src, compileJs);
}

function watchPhp() {
  watch(['./wp-content/themes/savez-tema/**/*.html', './wp-content/themes/savez-tema/**/*.php']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

// DEFAULT TASK
exports.default = series(compileSass, compileJs, parallel(sync, watchSass, watchJs, watchPhp))
```